# Cloning a EC2 Ubuntu instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, amazon-ami

I have an EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 instance with software, packages installed. I would like to clone or image this to spin up new instances so that it has all the software and packages installed rather than me doing them all over. It seems like the the AMI can create only linux images and not Ubuntu using the AWS console. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,
Kunal

Comment: Isn't Ubuntu a Linux distro? Stop your Ubuntu instance, create an AMI from it and launch more instances like it.

Comment: As I said, have tried does not work. You can try it for yourself using the free tier. The clone is always a other linux platform and not ubuntu. I am in us-west-1. Not sure if this region has messed up AMIs.

Comment: If the "clone" ends up as another Linux distro and not an identical copy of your Ubuntu instance then you are doing something very wrong. Your question really makes no sense, especially the part about Ubuntu not being Linux.

Comment: I did not claim ubuntu to be non-linux. I figured out the issue with aws support. The platform type is not getting recognized correctly (says other linux instead of ubuntu) but seems like it does not matter and I was clicking on re-boot when avoided doing that everything worked.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: I got same issues.... Ubuntu becomes Other Linux....

Answer (score 1):

A picture is worth a 1000 words. Have you tried this on your console?

[image]

When you launch a new instance, it will show up in "My AMIs" section, and it will have the same software and configurations of your EC2 instance.

Comment: Try ubuntu please with some custom package.

Comment: What do you mean by 'custom package'?

Comment: say a jq library, once you get an image and relaunch then the new ubuntu instance should have it.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And that is what happens. Still doesn't understand what seems to be your problem.

Comment: I figured out the issue with aws support. The platform type is not getting recognized correctly (says other linux instead of ubuntu) but seems like it does not matter and I was clicking on re-boot when avoided doing that everything worked.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: This is not an answer of question. I tried and ubuntu distro become other linux distro. Linux icon appeared instead of ubuntu. Bro i got your point please let me if you figured out.

Comment: @Kunal it worked without even rebooting, i use the ubuntu user instead of ec2-user and server let me in

Answer (score 0):

AWS lets you create AMI for all the Operating Systems it offers. It is not limited to one thing.

You can just create an AMI of your Ubuntu Instance and launch a new instance from it.

Just to clear your 2nd confusion, Ubuntu is also a LINUX OS.